# Cleaning up shared_context variables in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am using `RSpec.shared_context` to set variables that all the describe blocks will use.

Something like this

```
RSpec.shared_context "common" do 
  let(:name) { #creates a database object }
   #more let statements
end
```

Now I invoke it from describe block like so

```
describe "common test" do 
  include_context "common"
  #run few tests
end
```

Now after running the describe block I want to clean it up. How do I rollback all the objects created in the shared context?

I tried cleaning it in the `after(:context)` hook but since it is a let statement the variable `name` is only allowed inside examples.

Is there someway I can use `use_transactional_fixtures` to clean this up after running the tests in the describe block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about cleaning up your "lets" if you just setup your test suite properly to wipe the database.

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.
>
> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first
>   time the method it defines is invoked.

In almost every case you want teardown to happen automatically and per example. Thats what `config.transactional_fixtures` does - it rolls back the database after every example so that you have a fresh slate and don't get test ordering issues. Relying on each example / context whatever to explicitly clean up after itself is just a recipe for failure.